# Oracle beq and popen()

Tags: c, oracle, waitpid, oracle-pro-c, pclose

I have a program like this (that's for Pro*C precompiler):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
static VARCHAR ora_connect_str[81];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;

int main()
{
   FILE *f;
   int rc = 1;
   char *eptr=getenv("DB_LOGIN");

   strcpy(ora_connect_str.arr, eptr);
   ora_connect_str.len = strlen(eptr);

   EXEC SQL CONNECT :ora_connect_str;

   f=popen("exit 0", "r");
   rc = pclose(f);
   printf("errno=%d rc=%d\n", errno, rc);
}
```

When I use a tcp/ip connection to oracle, it works ok. But when I use BEQ, pclose() returns -1 with errno 10. Can someone direct me to a document(s) describing the possible issues with BEQ connections?
It appears that somewhere in the oracle's entrails there is wait() call already…

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:
http://openacs.org/forums/message-view?message_id=187522

The important section is:

```
  /* Restore SIGCHLD since Oracle10 client has trapped it **SG** */
  signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
```

Try adding it before your 'popen' call, it should work.

You will have to deal with whatever Oracle is trying to ignore though, or have zombie processes hanging.